# About $H^0(\mathcal{O}_X(-k))$ where $X$ is a curve on $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, sheaf-cohomology

$X$ is a locally complete intersection curve with each connected component X' satisfying $H^0(X',\mathcal{O}_{X'})=k$ on $\mathbb{P}^3_k$. There is an exact sequence for every $k\geq1$

$0 \to I_X(-k) \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(-k) \to \mathcal{O}_X(-k) \to 0$

I need to prove that $H^1(I_X(-k))=0$ for $k\geq1$, but looking at the exact sequence it is enough to show $H^0(\mathcal{O}_X (-k))=0$ since $H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(-k))=H^1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(-k))=0$.

Any suggestions on how to think about the global sections of $\mathcal{O}_X (-k)$? or on how to compute $H^1(I_X(-k))$? (at first I tried to look at the extensions)

Comment: Have you tried Riemann-Roch?

Comment: yes, I'm not sure how to use Riemann-Roch in this situation but I tried.
I tried to use Serre duality too.

Comment: Can you show $H^0(\mathcal{O}_{X'}(-k))=0$ for $k>0$? Then use the inclusion $\mathcal{O}_X\to \prod\mathcal{O}_{X'}$, the latter running through the connected components.